# Get values for customer note to order grid

Tags: admin, adminhtml, grid, ce-1.7.0.2

I need fast solution and I will temporarily change core class.

I need new element, customer note field in order grid (sales->orders). It already exist in database in
`sales_flat_order.customer_note`

In class:

`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid (\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php)`

I added this:

```
    $this->addColumn('customer_note', array(
        'header'       => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer note'),
        'index'        => 'customer_note'
    ));
```

Now I see customer note field, but it is empty, it shows no data. How can I get data in that field ?

(I am using Magento 1.7 and order comment field is suppressed with one plugin)

Comment: You have to create the column in the `sales_flat_order_grid` table. See linked duplicate for details

Comment: There is column in database ( ``sales_flat_order.customer_note``), and there is data in that column in DB, but when I add new field in order grid, he don't show data from that column, only empty column without data.

Comment: @IvanVulović sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_grid is 2 diff table. On each order place magento update the SFOG table using SFO data. Now you have the new column in SFO table but not in SFOG table. Either you need to create the new field in SFOG or join both tables and get the data from there.

Comment: If you go to `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Abstract.php` class check the function `afterCommitCallback()`. It updates the SFOG table after saving the order data to SFO.